# ReferenceError: User is not defined on callback

Tags: node.js, express, passport.js

I'm implementing a google login with node, express, and passport. After I click sign in, I get a User is not defined error when it's calling back to the page. It worked before but for some reason it doesn't now. Since the user isn't found, the session data is also not going to the database either. After sign in, the user is correctly signed into chrome.

Any suggestions on how to fix this issue?

```
  User.findOne({ "google.id": profile.id }, function (err, user) {
        ^

ReferenceError: User is not defined
```

app.js on localhost:3000

```
var createError = require("http-errors");
var express = require("express");
var path = require("path");
var cookieParser = require("cookie-parser");
var logger = require("morgan");
var passport = require("passport");
var bodyParser = require("body-parser");
var passport = require("passport");
var session = require("express-session");
var DynamoDBStore = require("connect-dynamodb")(session);
var GoogleStrategy = require("passport-google-oauth2").Strategy;
var AWS = require("aws-sdk");
var cors = require("cors");
require("dotenv").config({ path: __dirname + "/.env" });
var GOOGLE_CLIENT_ID = process.env.GOOGLE_CLIENT_ID;
var GOOGLE_CLIENT_SECRET = process.env.GOOGLE_CLIENT_SECRET;
var app = express();

passport.use(
  new GoogleStrategy(
    {
      clientID: GOOGLE_CLIENT_ID,
      clientSecret: GOOGLE_CLIENT_SECRET,
      
      callbackURL: "http://localhost:3000/auth/google/callback",
      passReqToCallback: true,
    },
    function (request, accessToken, refreshToken, profile, done) {
      // asynchronous verification, for effect...
      process.nextTick(function () {
        User.findOne({ "google.id": profile.id }, function (err, user) {
          if (err) return done(err);

          if (user) {
            // if a user is found, log them in
            return done(null, user);
          } else {
            // if the user isnt in our database, create a new user
            var newUser = new User();

            // set all of the relevant information
            newUser.google.id = profile.id;
            newUser.google.token = token;
            newUser.google.name = profile.displayName;
            newUser.google.email = profile.emails[0].value; // pull the first email

            // save the user
            newUser.save(function (err) {
              if (err) throw err;
              return done(null, newUser);
            });
          }
        });
      });
    }
  )
);
passport.serializeUser(function (user, done) {
  done(null, user);
});

passport.deserializeUser(function (obj, done) {
  console.log(obj);
  done(null, obj);
});

AWS.config.update({
  accessKeyId: process.env.ACCESS_KEY,
  secretAccessKey: process.env.ACCESS_KEY_SECRET,
  region: "us-west-1",
});

var dynamodb = new AWS.DynamoDB();
var server = require("http").createServer(app);

var userDrinksRouter = require("./routes/userDrinks");
var drinksRouter = require("./routes/drinks");
var ingredientsRouter = require("./routes/ingredients");
var liquorRouter = require("./routes/liquors");
var justIngredients = require("./routes/justIngredients");

app.use(function (req, res, next) {
  res.header("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", "http://localhost:3001");
  res.header("Access-Control-Allow-Credentials", true);
  res.header(
    "Access-Control-Allow-Headers",
    "Origin, X-Requested-With, Content-Type, Accept"
  );
  next();
});

app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: true }));
app.use(bodyParser.json());
app.use(cookieParser());
app.use(logger("dev"));


var options = {
  table: "app-sessions",
  AWSConfigJSON: {
    accessKeyId: process.env.ACCESS_KEY,
    secretAccessKey: process.env.ACCESS_KEY_SECRET,
    region: "us-west-1",
  },
  client: dynamodb,
};
//initialzie session
app.use(
  session({
    store: new DynamoDBStore(options),
    secret: "new user",
    resave: true,
    saveUninitialized: true,
  })
);
app.use(passport.initialize());
app.use(passport.session());
//   serialized and deserialized.
app.use((req, res, next) => {
  console.log(req.user);
  next();
});
app.get("/", function (req, res) {
  res.status(200).send({ user: req.user });
});

app.get("/account", ensureAuthenticated, function (req, res) {
  res.status(200).send({ user: req.user });
});

app.get("/login", function (req, res) {
  res.status(200).send({ user: req.user });
});
app.get("/users", function (req, res) {
  res.send({ user: req.user });
});


app.get(
  "/auth/google",
  passport.authenticate("google", {
    scope: ["profile", "email", "openid"],
  })
);


app.get(
  "/auth/google/callback",
  passport.authenticate("google", {
    failureRedirect: "/login",
  }),
  function (req, res) {
    res.redirect("http://localhost:3001/");
  }
);

app.get("/logout", function (req, res) {
  req.logout();
  res.redirect("http://localhost:3001/");
});

function ensureAuthenticated(req, res, next) {
  if (req.isAuthenticated()) {
    return next();
  }
  res.redirect("/login");
}

//app.use(ensureAuthenticated);
//app.use("/userDrinks", userDrinksRouter);
app.use("/drinks", drinksRouter);
app.use("/ingredients", ingredientsRouter);
app.use("/liquors", liquorRouter);
app.use("/justIngredients", justIngredients);


server.listen(3000, () => console.log("Drinks API listening on port 3000!"));
```

Comment: Have you imported `User` or defined it ??

Answer (score 0):

If I saw correctly, appears that you didn't import User, take a look on your requires.